Possible periodic boundary conditions for linear $n$-th order ordinary differential equations with constant coefficients over an interval
Suppose that $I$ is an interval. For simplicity, $I = (0,1)$. I am interested in linear $n$-th order boundary value problems with constant coefficients, the prototype of which is:
$$
a_n u^{(n)}(x) + a_{n-1} u^{(n-1)}(x) + \dots + a_2 u''(x) + a_1 u'(x) + a_0 u(x) = f(x)
$$
where $a_n, \dots, a_0 \in \mathbb R$ are real numbers and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a function. For simplicity, $f$ is continuous.
What are natural choices of periodic boundary conditions for such a differential equations? Are there values of $n$ where the problem becomes underdetermined or ill-posed, regardless of the coefficients? For example, given $n$, to what order can I impose periodic boundary conditions?
For example, in the case $n=2$, imposing periodic boundary conditions of Dirichlet type,
$$ u(0) = u(1)$$
generally leads to solvable problem whose solution is unique up to constants. What if I impose periodic Neumann boundary conditions,
$$ u'(0) = u'(1)$$
or I choose to impose both periodic boundary conditions,
$$ u(0) = u(1), \quad u'(0) = u'(1)?$$
Of course, the same question can be asked for any higher-order differential equation, including of odd order. For example, what in the case $n=5$?

A solution to your $n^{\text{th}}$ order ODE will be the sum of a particular solution (yielding $f(x)$ on the right hand side) and a homogeneous solution (yielding $0$ on the right hand side). The homogeneous solution will in general consist of a sum of $n$ functions with $n$ unknown coefficients to be determined by boundary conditions. Since there are $n$ unknowns, you can impose $n$ periodic boundary conditions going from $u(0) = u(1)$ up to $u^{(n-1)}(0) = u^{(n-1)}(1)$.
